# How can I open csv file received from axios get response in new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, token

Good day.
I had such a construction and it worked.

```
       axios.post(url, testsToExportToCsv)
            .then(response => {
                let win = window.open(response.data.uri, '_blank');
                win.focus();
            });
```

But then there were implemented some tokens with headers on project, so I cannot use plain window.open - it won't let me because of the security.

I rewrite that code:

```
        axiosWithHeaders.post(url, testsToExportToCsv)
            .then(response => {
                axiosWithHeaders
                    .get(response.data.uri)  // receiving the link
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log("response", response)
                        // and here I need to put some code to open CSV from response.data
                     
                    })

            });
```

Please, don't take `axiosWithHeaders` into the count - it works well, it is just axios with tokens underneath.

So, I successfully obtain CSV file in response. But I need to show it in new window as CSV, how this could be done?

I've tried similar

```
                    let win = window.open(response.data);
                     win.focus();
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after spending several hours this works

```
        axiosWithHeaders.post(url, testsToExportToCsv)
            .then(response => {
                nameOfTheCsv = response.data.name;
                axiosWithHeaders
                    .get(response.data.uri, {responseType: 'blob'})
                    .then(response => {
                        const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                        const link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = downloadUrl;
                        link.setAttribute('download', nameOfTheCsv);
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        link.remove();
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) from the CSV, and use the [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method to create a data URL for it, which you can then send to `window.open`.

```js
const csv = await axios.post(url, testsToExportToCsv);

const dataUri = window.URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob( [csv], { type: "text/csv" } )
);

window.open(dataUri);
```